# CSS code for "inserting a custom post divider" after each post

Tags: posts, loop, code

I want to add a custom post divider to separate my posts. I'm using the Enfold theme in WordPress.org. I've searched for the answer to my question but I don't understand the coding language.

I understand that WordPress uses a post loop. And somehow I can include code within the loop to produce my custom divider. I don't get it when I'm looking at the code.

This is the latest code I generated with Short Code Ultimate:

```
[su_posts posts_per_page="4" tax_term="37,38,48,49,17,18,50,35,51,1" tax_operator="0" order="desc"]
```

This is the code I'm picking up from this forum:

```
while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();

    the_title();
    the_excerpt();

    // if current_post is 1, insert the div
    // note that current_post starts at 0,
    // so this will be after the second post's content

    if( 1 == $wp_query->current_post ):
        echo '<div>My div!</div>';
    endif;

endwhile;
```

Would someone kindly show me how to format the code within the WordPress loop to include my custom post divider?

Comment: The code you've posted will put a divider *only* after the *second* post. It sounds like you want dividers after every post. Furthermore, there's a difference between a post loop in a template file and a shortcode in the post editor (though it may invoke a loop, you probably can't edit it). It sounds like you just need to add some CSS to put a border between posts. If that's the case, you should post your HTML output on a site like StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

With this code the divider is inserted between posts, checks if the current post is the first one, and if it isn't, it inserts the divider. This avoids the divider to show up after the last post, and before the first one.

```
while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();

    if( 0 < $wp_query->current_post ):
        echo '<div>My div!</div>';
    endif;

    the_title();
    the_excerpt();


endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( 0 == $wpsites_query->current_post ):
    echo '<div>My div!</div>';
endif;
```

This will output your div after each excerpt.

This is what i tested using a custom function. Replace the genesis hook with a WordPress equivalent.

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_entry', 'wpsites_after_excerpt' );
function wpsites_after_excerpt() {

if( is_home() && 0 == $wp_query->current_post ){
    echo 'Some Text';
    }
}
```

[Source](http://wp.me/p1lTu0-aiE)

Comment: That condition is true just for the first post.

Comment: When i tested it in a custom function, it displays the content after every post in the loop.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. `current_post` is the "index" of the Loop, it increments every time you call `the_post`, so it's true just the first time `the_post` is called.

Comment: Only after first post for me too (tested on main query), which is what I would expect. I am not sure what might make counter not tick properly.

Comment: Updated my answer and it works perfectly.

Comment: I do think that genesis uses a custom loop and not the main query, because your code cannot work. Have you tested this on a bundled theme? `0 == $wp_query->current_post` only returns true on the first post

Comment: That's right. Custom loop.

Comment: AHA, that is why `0 == $wp_query->current_post` supposedly returns true on every post. If you change `$wp_query` to the variable attached to `new WP_Query` which genesis uses for it's custom loop, your results will be returned as explained, and that in `0` will only be true on the first post :-)

Comment: Deserves an upvote i think @goose

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use custom CSS to do this. WordPress 4.7 now has a custom CSS function built in, which makes it easier than editing theme files. As you have not provided a link to your site, we can't tell you the HTML element to target with your CSS, however.